# IntelliJ Plugin - Needs to hook into existing actions

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm writing a plugin to IntelliJ, and need to hook into some of the existing actions that already exist, like when a file is saved, the code is compiled, or a refactoring happens. I wasn't able to find any info on the plugin site about existing actions, only new actions.

These posts are similar: 
[Save actions in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707316/save-actions-in-intellij-idea) 
[Intellij reformat on file save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946993/intellij-reformat-on-file-save)

but since they don't include actually writing a plugin, I'm hoping there may be some internal hook for doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the code [example](http://arhipov.blogspot.com/2011/04/code-snippet-intercepting-on-save.html) of how to intercept 'on save' event by a custom plugin.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Accepted because you sent me the example code.

Comment: @Anton Do you know how I can hook in and abort close tab ?

Answer (score 4):

You can hook into 'flush changes to file system' processing via [FileDocumentManagerListener](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/fileEditor/FileDocumentManagerListener.java) registered at the [FILE_DOCUMENT_SYNC](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/AppTopics.java) topic.

You can get more information about IJ messaging [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+Messaging+infrastructure).

Comment: This looks promising. I guess you can't get much more authoritative than one of Idea's authors :)