# Execute command on saving a file in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to run a script when a file gets saved.  (It's an automatic git commit in the vein of [git-wip](https://github.com/bartman/git-wip)).  It's related to [Save actions in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707316/save-actions-in-intellij-idea), but it mostly attracted answers about code reformatting.  It was also asked 3 years ago.  The only snippet I found was http://arhipov.blogspot.hu/2011/04/code-snippet-intercepting-on-save.html. So I wonder if things have changed and now it's easy to add a save-hook.

Comment: You may want to ask your question in the IntelliJ IDEA _Open API and Plugin Development_ forum: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/idea/open_api_and_plugin_development?view=discussions

Comment: It doesn't sound like a good idea anyway. IntelliJ saves changes very frequently, so it would make a mess of your commit history and eat your processing resources.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you have at least two options:

1. Use the File Watchers plugin from JetBrains:

   - Plugin: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pr=idea&pluginId=7177
   - Doc: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-file-watchers.html

   NB: Doesn't work on IntelliJ Idea 11.
2. Use a similar program outside of IntelliJ. I'm using fswatch (works on Unix-based OSes, including OSX) installed via MacPorts (port install fswatch):

   https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch

Comment: The file watchers plugin worked beautifully to run a custom script after every save of a file.