# In PyCharm, is it possible to do "the Reformat Code" every time I save a file?

Tags: pycharm

I would like to automatically reformat the code in a file whenever I save it. Is it possible to do it in PyCharm? So far, this is the only feature from Eclipse I cannot find in PyCharm.

If it is possible, can you please point me to the setting. I have gone through the preferences and looked around the Internet but am unable to find this setting (if it exists).

P.S. PyCharm devs: if this does not exist, it is at the top of my PyCharm wish list.

Comment: Probably not, but you can try a trick from Idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5581992/313516 (PyCharm and IntelliJ Idea have a common codebase).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intellij reformat on file save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946993/intellij-reformat-on-file-save)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save actions in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707316/save-actions-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JetBrains team is working on ability to have on-save-actions. You'll be able to record a macro of what actions need to happen when you hit Ctrl/Command+S. Not sure when this will be released though.

More information at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6722

Answer (score 6):

There's a plugin for that attached to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5806
The comments to the issue also explain why it hasn't been implemented as a core product feature.

Answer (score 5):

Jetbrains have implemented `Actions on save` in PyCharm.

Actions on Save page has been added to Settings (Preferences) in 2021.2. At the moment it contains the following options:

- Reformat code (if VCS is used it has a choice Whole file <-> Changed lines)
- Optimize imports
- Rearrange code
- Code cleanup (applies fixes from the code cleanup inspections)

Also, there's a bunch of 'actions on save' that have already been available in the previous IDE versions and could be configured on their own technology-specific pages in Settings. It's now possible to enable/disable these features right on the Actions on Save page without jumping to technology-specific page. Note, that all these options remain available on the technology-specific page and UI is in sync with Actions on Save page.

- Run eslint --fix (provided by the JavaScript plugin)
- Run Prettier (provided by the Prettier plugin)
- Build project (only in the IDEs that support Java)
- Run File Watchers (provided by the File Watchers plugin)
- Upload to default server (provided by the FTP/SFTP Connectivity plugin)

[image: IDE screenshot]

For details check this link:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100701#focus=Comments-27-4985850.0-0

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the image (shown below for MAC, but should be same for windows I think)

1. Go to Settings
2. Tools
3. Actions on Save
4. Check the option "Reformat code"
5. Apply

Now when you make changes and save (ctrl+s or cmd+s) the code should be reformatted.

[image]